# Sort array data without duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, twitter

I'm making a twitter bot using Codebird.

I want to sort the data status in php array without duplicates. Line by line (urls media /remote file links)

This my code:

```
require_once ('codebird.php');
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("pubTRI3ik5hJqxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxS6Uj1t5GJPi6AUxxxxx");

$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();

$cb->setToken("xxxxxxx-aVixxxxxxxxxX5MsEHEK", "Dol6RMhOYgxxxxxxFnDtJ6IzXMOLyt");

$statusimgs = array (
    "/images.com/hfskehfskea33/jshdfjsh.jpeg",
"/pic.images.com/SDjhs33/sZddszf.jpeg",
"/pic.images.com/dfggfd/dgfgfgdg.jpeg",
"//pic.images.com/xgxg/xdgxg6.jpeg",
);

$params = array(
  'status' => 'halo my ststus',
  'media[]' => $statusimgs[array_rand($statusimgs)]
);

$reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
```

Initially I use random array, but this can make duplicate photos.

I want to sort link remote files from first line to last. I have 1-100 link images to upload on twitter from remote file methot. One by one when script execute manual or with cron.

I want set cron every 60s , 60s 1 photo tweet.

Comment: You should focus your question on one problem. Your question is a bit confusing to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as "Remove duplicates from an array and sort it".
So, you could try this:

- Make $statusarray unique,
- sort $statusarray,
- add $statusarray to $params array (key = 'media').

### Code

```
    <?php
        // Input array
        $statusimgs = array (
            "/images.com/hfskehfskea33/jshdfjsh.jpeg",
            "/pic.images.com/SDjhs33/sZddszf.jpeg",
            "/pic.images.com/dfggfd/dgfgfgdg.jpeg",
            "/pic.images.com/dfggfd/dgfgfgdg.jpeg",
            "/pic.images.com/xgxg/xdgxg6.jpeg",
            "/pic.images.com/xgxg/xdgxg6.jpeg",
            "/pic.images.com/xgxg/xdgxg6.jpeg",
        );

        // Make unique and sort
        $statusimgs = array_unique($statusimgs, SORT_STRING);
        sort($statusimgs,SORT_STRING);

        // Create the resulting $params array
        $params = array(
            'status' => 'halo my ststus',
            'media' => $statusimgs
        );

        // Display the result
        echo '<pre>'; var_dump($params); '</pre>';

        //$reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
    ?>
```

### Result

```
array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(14) "halo my ststus"
  ["media"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=> string(39) "/images.com/hfskehfskea33/jshdfjsh.jpeg"
    [1]=> string(36) "/pic.images.com/SDjhs33/sZddszf.jpeg"
    [2]=> string(36) "/pic.images.com/dfggfd/dgfgfgdg.jpeg"
    [3]=> string(32) "/pic.images.com/xgxg/xdgxg6.jpeg"
  }
}
```

### Alternative Code

```
<?php
$statusimgs = array (
    "/images.com/hfskehfskea33/jshdfjsh.jpeg",
    "/pic.images.com/SDjhs33/sZddszf.jpeg",
    "/pic.images.com/dfggfd/dgfgfgdg.jpeg",
    "/pic.images.com/dfggfd/dgfgfgdg.jpeg",
    "/pic.images.com/xgxg/xdgxg6.jpeg",
    "/pic.images.com/xgxg/xdgxg6.jpeg",
    "/pic.images.com/xgxg/xdgxg6.jpeg",
);

$statusimgs = array_unique($statusimgs, SORT_STRING);
sort($statusimgs,SORT_STRING);

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['index'])) {
    $_SESSION['index'] = 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION['index'] = ($_SESSION['index']>=count($statusimgs)) ? 1 : $_SESSION['index']+1;
}
session_write_close();

$params = array(
    'status' => 'halo my ststus',
    'media' => $statusimgs
);

// echo '<pre>'; var_dump($params); '</pre>';
echo 'Choosen: ' . $params['media'][$_SESSION['index']-1] . '<br />';

//$reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
?>
```

Comment: not work.. how to get array data sort 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8... one per one, when script execute first, get data [1] (line first of array), and when script execute again in second ,array not get [1] ,but get [2] , if script exe again 3rd, not get [1],[2], but get [3] ,,,, etc.. What needs to be given cache ?

Comment: My script **always produces exactly the same result** based on the given input array _$statusimgs_ (I added it to my answer). I tried to figure out what you are looking for, from your question. Maybe I got it wrong, and maybe you should ask more precisely and more focused! About what an array 1,2,,3,4.. are you talking?

Comment: If you wish to show one picture after one within a session you could use **session\_start()** and keep the index in a **$\_SESSION** variable, incrementing each time and rolling over if necessary. You then probably only would need to remove duplicates from your input array (_array\_unique(...)_)

Comment: I just added an alternative with the $_SESSION variable I proposed above.

Comment: i only show result link (in array) to upload on twitter .with sort without duplicate ...

but i have any idea , make link in array to txt file , and make function for read the first line of the txt file then delete that line after file execute...

Comment: Hmmm. I'm afraid I don't understand what you want to do. Of course you could create a link. And of course you could write the links to a text file and delete the top line when used. Can you show us example code (php, html, ...) of what the result should look like, and describe the conditions (when the user / any user has clicked...). Btw: have you tried my example and seen what the results are (the 1st, next time you execute it)?